# Increment Dictionary Value in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, findandmodify

I have the following object:

```
[BsonId]
public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
public string Area { get; set; }
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
public int MethodCalls { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, ActionStats> Actions { get; set; }
```

The ActionStats object looks like this:

```
public string Action { get; set; }
public int Count { get; set; }
public long TotalDuration { get; set; }
public Dictionary<int, int> Hourly { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to update the values in the using a FindAndModify like this:

```
Update<Statistic>.Inc(x => x.MethodCalls, 1).Inc(x => x.Actions[action.ToLower()].Count, 1);
```

However this fails on the second increment statement with the following stack trace:

> Stack Trace -- at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.VisitGetItem(MethodCallExpression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionVisitor`1.Visit(Expression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.Visit(Expression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionVisitor`1.Visit(Expression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.Visit(Expression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.ExpressionVisitor`1.Visit(Expression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.Visit(Expression node)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Utils.BsonSerializationInfoFinder.GetSerializationInfo(Expression node, Dictionary`2 serializationInfoCache)
>   at MongoDB.Driver.Builders.UpdateBuilder`1.Inc(Expression`1 memberExpression, Int32 value)

How do I go about update the dictionary values of a subdocuments?

Comment: It looks like a parse issue. Are you sure you got a integer in your database?

Comment: Yes, if i do Update.Inc("Actions.timesheetrows.Count", 1); then it works fine but I want to be able to do this dynamically via linq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt if the behavior is implemented because of the MongoDB Official JIRA issue [CSHARP-917](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-917). However, you can always do it another way:

```
Update.Inc(string.Format("Actions.{0}.Count", action.ToLower()), 1);
```

Comment: This looks like it's solved it until that JIRA issue is fixed, just looking to avoid having strings everywhere.