# MongoDB .NET Driver - Increment a value inside dictionary

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-update

I need to increment a value that is stored inside a dictionary, the structure of my object is (basically) the following:

```cs
public class OrderDetails : EntityBase
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, int> TotalViewsPerUser { get; set; }
}
```

As this object can be competed between several requests, I can't just bring the object to the server, increment the value and then save it again.

So, what I need to do is increment the value of the variable `TotalViewsPerUser`, the dictionary key is the `UserId`.
If there is no key, I need to insert the key and start with the value 1.

I looked for some examples, of the use of "Inc" and I found the following example, but, I could not make it work, because Mongo would not insert the key.

What I did is:

```cs
var update = Builders<OrderDetails>.Update
            .Inc($"totalViewsPerUser.{userId}.v", 1);
```

[Increment Dictionary Value in MongoDB C# Driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683455/increment-dictionary-value-in-mongodb-c-sharp-driver)

Answer (score 2):

From [`$inc` Behavior](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/update/inc/#behavior),

> If the field does not exist, $inc creates the field and sets the field to the specified value.

While `TotalViewsPerUser` is `Dictionary<int, int>` type, the value would be:

```
"totalViewsPerUser" : {
  1: 1
}
```

in the document. You should not specify the `.v` for the update field.

```cs
var update = Builders<OrderDetails>.Update
    .Inc($"totalViewsPerUser.{userId}", 1);

UpdateResult updateResult = _collection.UpdateMany(
    FilterDefinition<OrderDetails>.Empty,
    update);
```

> Demo

[image]